# How to analyze the video frame and do the image processing on it based on realtime?

Tags: android, multithreading, video, opengl-es, real-time

**What I try to do**

---

I made a video player app by using the source code from the following link.

https://github.com/kylelo/VideoPlayerGH

I want to implement some methods to calculate the complexity for each frame, then I can do some image processing after the calculation.

So the first step I need to do is to get the bitmap or pixel values from the video frame to analyze before it render on the screen, I have used **glReadPixels()** to get the pixel values into a new **ByteBuffer**  in the **draw()** function. I can get the RGBA values successfully, but the frame rate droped from 60 fps to 20 fps on my device(HTC buffterfly s), I even have not did any image processing on it...

---

**My question is**

---

Is there any other more efficient way to realize this task? Even working on other layers of Android system is fine.

I really need some hints on it...

Because I am new in Android, so if there is any concept I am wrong, please tell me! I am really appreciate for everyone's help!

Comment: If you're sending the frames to a TextureView, you can receive `onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` callbacks, and use `getBitmap()` to extract the frame. This will be happening after the frame is sent to the TextureView for display; if you need to do it before, you'll want to send the video to your own SurfaceTexture, do the analysis, then render the frame yourself. (The sample code you linked to seems to do something like the latter.)

Comment: @fadden I am really thanks for your tips! 
It seems that I have to get the frame info from the **SurfaceTexture** before it renders to the screen.
But, after I looked up some information, I still can't find out the method to get the image info(i.e: bitmaps, pixel-value array... ) which can be analyzed. Could you give me some hints about it? Thank you:)